# Tutorials/resources for building a toy SMT solver

Tags: smt-solvers

I've built a rudimentary SAT Solver from scratch, and wanted to do the same with SMT solvers as well.

While I've found two toy SMT Solver implementations in [Haskell](https://github.com/beala/smt) and [Ocaml](https://github.com/Ekdohibs/toy-smt), but no tutorials or examples, which is a stark contrast from all SAT Solver tutorials out there.

Is there a resource for building a toy SMT Solver from scratch?

Comment: That's quite an interesting point. I personally would follow the SAT ones and then "modify" it towards an SMT. There are plenty of examples with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the material on [Leonardo de Moura's website](https://leodemoura.github.io/). For starters, I can recommend the talk he gave at the Aalto SAT/SMT Summer School in 2013 titled [Internals of SMT solvers](https://leodemoura.github.io/files/SATSMT2013.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

I think [these slides](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11801882/gust?tab=questions&sort=newest) give a foundation of building a SMT solver, somewhat

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 1) Unfortunately, your link doesn't work. 2) If it's applicable here, can you please also summarize the main points of the link? [Link-only answers can be broken someday and have other issues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/711182) 3) The general meeting of an "accepted answer" is that it solves the problem. As I understand, you currently don't know whether the slides will actually help you to build a SMT solver, so I'm not sure that the answer should be accepted.